# MVC3 ViewBag doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I am trying to display price in Index file.
However, it showed blank field. What's wrong with my coding?
Could you help me? it should be easy problem. But I cannot find it.
If you give some feedback, I am really thank you!

```
 public ActionResult Index(decimal priceValue)
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Set up our ViewModel
        decimal price = priceValue;
        ViewBag.eachPrice = price;
        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(price)
        };

        // Return the view
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
{
    <tr id="row-@item.recordId">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Product.model, "Details", "Store", new { id = item.productId }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            //here!! is it wrong?
            @ViewBag.eachPrice
        </td>
        <td id="item-count-@item.recordId">
            @item.count
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.dateCreated.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
        </td>
        <td>
            @*how about using some model instead of number?*@
            @item.dateCreated.Date.AddDays(2).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.recordId">
            Remove from cart</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: the code as it looks, it should work, have you tried debugging the View and see whether the value is there ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved the error I don't know why before it does not work..
Anyway, thanks you guys for replying!

Answer (score 0):

In VB, i do this like that :

```
 @code
   Dim price = viewbag.price
 @End code
```

and then, I display the value where I want

```
 @Html.Raw(price)
```

In cs, I think you must put a "var" in place of "Dim", and finish the instruction with a ";"

Comment: In C# (not sure about VB, but I suppose they work the same way) it normally doesn't matter if you use @ViewBag.price or if you store it in a variable first.

Comment: It has never worked for me the way you describe it. But I maybe also did something wrong (I almost have no experience in .Net)

Comment: asp.net mvc stores the title in the viewbag, and usually I want the same title on top of the page, so I use `<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>`. The problem here shouldn't be different.